# Is it "secure" to store a password and username in a .env file in a server to validate an admin API endpoint against?

Tags: rest, security, rust, environment-variables, actix-web

**Context**

I've build a RESTful API server in Actix-Web with Rust that's hosted on a Heroku paid plan. It has n amount of publicly available endpoints to access content, alongside 3 strictly admin-only endpoints (for creating, editing, and deleting public content).

I am the *only* developer who'd ever need to access the admin-only endpoints - and infrequently at that. Several *random* users will be using the publicly available endpoints daily.

Normally, I'd implement an authentication/authorization strategy akin to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbsmsi7l3r4) using JWTs (but obviously in Rust for my case). However, the added complexity that comes with this "more common" solution seems overkill for my simple use-case.

**My theorized solution**

Could I add a `username` and `password` field to the `.env` file in my project like so in order to match against a username and password passed in the admin-only handler functions?

```
... OTHER KEYS ...
USERNAME = my_really_long_random_username
PASSWORD = my_really_long_random_password
```

At first glance I'm storing passwords in plain text... but, there's only 1 and it's in my `.env` file, which is private by default.

All I'd do for the admin-only routes then is this (pseudo-code):

```rust
pub fn router_handler(passed_data) -> HttpResponse {
    if passed_data.username == env.username && passed_data.password == env.password {
        // CONSIDER THEM ADMIN
    } else {
        // BLOCK THEM AS THEY'RE NOT AUTHENTICATED
    }
}
```

**What I've tried**

I have yet to try this strategy, but I'm curious about your opinions on it.

**Question**

Is my theorized solution secure? Does it seem reasonable given my use-case?

---

**Response to question: jthulhu - is this what I do?**

So, my `.env` file should look something like this:

```
... OTHER KEYS ...
USERNAME = a98ysnrn938qwyanr9c8yQden 
PASSWORD = aosdf83h282huciquhr8291h91
```

where both of those hashes are the results of running my pre-determined username and password through my `to_hash` function which I added below (likely using a lib like [this](https://docs.rs/rust-argon2/latest/argon2/)).

Then, my handler should be like this (psuedo-code):

```rust
pub fn router_handler(passed_data) -> HttpResponse {
    if to_hash(passed_data.username) == env.username && to_hash(passed_data.password) == env.password {
        // CONSIDER THEM ADMIN
    } else {
        // BLOCK THEM AS THEY'RE NOT AUTHENTICATED
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to know the rule that **you should never store plain-text passwords**, but maybe you don't know why (after all, if you store it in a *private* file, what could happen?). There are theoretical, security considerations that should make you refrain from doing so (ie. what if an attacker breaks through one layer of your private stuff, is that enough to basically access the password and get access to *everything* else?), but the very concrete reason why you shouldn't do this is: it's actually extremely simple to not do so. Just hash your password (with salt!), and store the hash.

Comment: So, basically, no don't store your passwords as text, even in your use-case.

Comment: @jthulhu So, I'd basically be able to do this, but only if I store the results of the hashes in the `.env` (to compare the handler to) and then accept the plain-text username and password from the handler, which I then quickly hash to compare to the already-hashed .env versions? I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes. You could store them however you want (in a database, even simple ones like sqlite; in a file, like your OS does; ...). Note that usually web services do not hash usernames, because that means being unable to retrieve the username for a given user.

Comment: Ok, that sounds great! I'll just hash just the password, and store in in my .env, but look into sqlite if I ever need to add more users as admins. If you wanna write your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: If you move beyond a file-based solution, I'd suggest looking into a database server instead of sqlite since with any web-based service you'll almost certainly have to deal with concurrent sessions accessing (and potentially modifying) the database simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store passwords in plain text in a server, because if someones breaks in your server, and can read that file, they now have access to everything (whereas they might previously not). Not only that, but most people tend to reuse passwords, so storing one password in plain text means exposing several services where that password is used.

Instead, you should hash the passwords and store the hash. To perform a login, check if the hash of the given password corresponds to the one stored. This mechanism can be used with files or with databases alike, and is pretty much independent on how you actually store the hashes.